# Exposing my localhost on vagrant over https not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https, vagrant

I am trying to expose my dev environment over https on vagrant. My vagrantfile is below.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
end
```

The commands I run on the vagrant box are

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

I then share the vagrant box

```
vagrant share --https 443
```

When I go to the url provided by vagrant over http I get the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

When I go to the url provided by vagrant over https I get a blank page and

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I have googled endlessly and tried various solutions, but nothing is working.

Creating a cert with openssl, does not work either.

Comment: What is the output when you run `vagrant share --https 443` ?

Comment: It outputs the URL for the publicly shared box. I am not 100% sure how the flag --https 443 relates to the host/guest in the vagrantfile.

Comment: `500` error sounds like you have an error from the server running from vagrant - did you look at the log from your vagrant server ? can you make sure to forward `https` port : `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: xxxx`

Comment: Yes, but it didn't provide any help. I ended up moving using nginx since this is just a test and it's working fine. I would still be interested in why this isn't working on apache.